# in-app-purchase: how about this scenario?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm designing an ios app with the following set of features:

1. user downloads the app and creates an account on my server.
2. user uploads content (video, images etc.) **by logging into a companion website using a mac or pc.**
3. uploaded content is enriched (audio smoothed, filters applied etc) on my server side.
4. app downloads the enriched file.
5. user shares his enriched file with other users using the app.

my questions are:

1. can iap be used to pay for the cost of step 2 above? (storage of uploaded file for retrieval by the app, bandwidth, cost of enriching the file etc)
2. can iap be used for step 5 above? (invitation to other users so that they can share content)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable functionality in your app based on the user purchases, that's a totally common feature. You can have a disabled button until the user purchases that functionality.

About that if your project is viable or not, I can't answer, but about enabling functionality as I said, the answer is yes.

Comment: edited point 2 on top to clarify the purchase (if Apple allows it) enables user to 'log into the companion website', but the quote below from the 'In-App Purchase Programming Guide' seems to apply it's not possible. "You can’t use In-App Purchase to sell real-world goods and services or to sell unsuitable content.
Real-world goods and services. You must deliver a digital good or service within your app when using In-App Purchase. Use a different payment mechanism to let your users buy real-world goods and services in your app, such as a credit card or payment service."

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse you can! For this, you can add your products on iTunesConnect and use those products in your code to implement in app purchase. Logic will be just start product request when user taps on the button whoose action is desired to be ourchased.

Comment: Please check my edit: the iap purchase enables user to upload more files from the companion website, so aren't the 'digital goods' not delivered within the app which goes against Apple's guidelines in the 'In-App Purchase Programming Guide'?